# Make images appear randomly and disappear after certain time

Tags: python, pygame

I am extremely confused as to how to approach this and I can't get it to work. So, if you have played snake before you will remember that at certain times an image would appear that if you ate that, you would get more points but if you missed it, it would disappear (i.e not stay there forever until you caught it.)

I have written code that works with time (allowing you to activate a shield) as below:

---

```
if (count % 35 == 0):

    ang = random.choice(angles)
    particles.append(Particle(red, 5, ang, user))
    score += 10
    score_graphic = font.render("Score " + str(score), 1, white)

    total_shields += 1

    if total_shields > 10:
        total_shields = 10

count += 1

curr_time = time.time()

if space_press:
    if (curr_time - new_time) > 0.3:
        new_time = time.time()
        total_shields -= 1

    shield_on = total_shields > 0
```

---

How can I implement the disappearing image in pygame?
I know this is unconventional, but if you could help, I'd appreciate as I have not been able to do it for the past hour.

Best,
Seyed

Comment: use `hide_time = curr_time + random_time` and check `hide_time` in mainloop to display or not display image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use variables with time of `start showing` and `end showing`.

It is popular method to control different elements in game.

```
import pygame
import random

# - init -

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))

# - objects -

display_apple = False
start_showing = None
end_showing = None

current_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()

# show first time 
start_showing = current_time + random.randint(1,5)*1000

# - mainloop -

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

running = True

while running:

    # - events -

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                running = False

    # - updates -

    current_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()

    if display_apple:
        # is it time to hide ?
        if end_showing and current_time >= end_showing:
            # hide it
            display_apple = False
            end_showinge = False
            # set time when to show
            start_showing = current_time + random.randint(1,5)*1000
    else:
        # is it time to show ?
        if start_showing and current_time >= start_showing:
            # show it
            display_apple = True
            start_showing = False
            # set time when to hide
            end_showing = current_time + random.randint(1,5)*1000

    # - draws -

    screen.fill((0,0,0))

    if display_apple:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255,0,0), (0,0,100,100))

    pygame.display.flip()

    # - FPS -

    clock.tick(30)

# - end -

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: But I have a little problem, your code generates a particle at a random time in a fixed position, I want fixed time random position. How can I do that?

Comment: read code in part `# -updates -` - use fixed time instead of random and add random position.